# iCloud password change: "Enter Password for Other MacBook Pro”?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, error-logging, apple-id

Error message when attempting to change my iCloud password:

[image: Error message when attempting to change my iCloud password]

> #### Enter Password for Other MacBook Pro
>
> Enter the password for “___ MacBook Pro”, which is not the password for this MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 1):

It's part of Apple's authentication method.  I ran into this recently too.  To change your iCloud password, you can be prompted to enter an authorization code sent to your cell phone and/or prompted for your password on another device logged into iCloud.  I have no idea how Apple knows what the password is on your other machine (that's kind of scary), but this is legit.

Comment: The same way they know your iCloud password: By storing it as a hash. That doesn't mean Apple knows the plaintext password.

Comment: OK, but it also means that they're uploading your (local) Mac passwords to their servers.  Even by doing it as a hash, that seems a little weird.  I know, I gave up my privacy to Apple, Amazon, and Google a long time ago (Alexa could be interpreting what I'm typing my listening to my keystroke patterns! :-)), but it seems strange to upload a local password, in any format...

Comment: Not necessarily. Apple cares much more about UX than they do about security best practices. And if they store the password with something like Argon2id, then even if it were to leak, only the weakest passwords would be crackable.

Comment: scarier is that I have no attached device and no other mac to speak of.

Comment: OK, this *could* be a bug, but isn't it possible that you (or someone in your family) was given a "school loaner MacBook" as shown, and logged in (even once) with your iCloud acct?  Behind the "top" pop-up, I can see a link "Forgot MacBook Pro Password", so you'll have to click that.

Answer (score 1):

Some secrets are so sensitive (such as your iCloud Keychain) that Apple does not want to have any ability to access them, for example, if the FBI wanted them. For these secrets, Apple does not want to have the information to decrypt them, but of course it also wants to be careful about who gets even the encrypted information, because encrypted information is not impossible to decode, just difficult.

So what Apple does is use regular iCloud authentication to sync these encrypted secrets that can only be decrypted by the keys that are only stored on the devices.

When you add a new device, you are asking to be let into the circle of trust and get access to these secrets. How can Apple do that while at the same time keeping the FBI or anyone who has broken into your iCloud account from doing the same thing? Apparently the solution Apple came up with is to encrypt or hash the device password of devices already in the circle of trust and allow in whoever can prove that they know the password of one of the devices.

Note also that Apple seems to have changed their mind about this method, probably because of the confusion and suspicion it raised. According to their Spring 2020 "Apple Platform Security" whitepaper (currently [here](https://manuals.info.apple.com/MANUALS/1000/MA1902/en_US/apple-platform-security-guide.pdf), but who knows for how long), they now require the approval to come directly from a device already in the circle.